# Is it possible to generate a QR Code without error correction?

Tags: qr-code, error-correction

Still include the mode indicator, string length, and data...I was hoping there was an option to just leave the remaining error correction bits as 0's?

I'm making the QR Code in assembly (MIPS) for a class project. Implementing the Reed Solomon Algorithm is becoming quite a bear.

Comment: What does assembly have to do with this question? You should remove the tag.

Answer (score 3):

The *lowest* level of error correction is 7% - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Error_correction

Here's a sample code with "L" level correction.  If you cover one or two blocks, the code is still readable.  Much more than that and information cannot be recovered.

[image]

You could, theoretically, mask out the error corrective bits when you generate the QR code - but I'm not entirely sure why you would do so.

Comment: Looking back on this 8 years (lol) later, to be more specific, I was wondering if masking out the error-correction bits was still in spec? And if that would still be a scannable QR code (assuming no other bits were lost)? 
I was asking because I tried this, and the code would not scan. I was wondering if I had made an error in generating the QR code, or if this was not allowed in the QR specification, and was not scanning... by design.

Comment: I think the answer is that the scanner *needs* to see the error correction bits. Otherwise it won't be able to ascertain if the code is damaged.